# How to add items to cart in laravel?

Tags: laravel, e-commerce, laravel-8

I am making a ecommerce app. I want to know that how can i add item to cart , I not wanted any code please help me.

How I add item in cart.

**I only want idea**

[image]

I am saying that when i press add to cart button it will show in cart

Comment: Please describe your problem a little more precise so we can help you better

Comment: I am saying that when i press add to cart button it will show in cart. see the image for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you usually create a relation of M:N like this:

- Cart (Model)
- Item (Model)
- CartItem (Pivot) - attribute quantity

you can enhance it by connecting the cart with user/cookie.

Afterwards you put methods into model (or even better create helper class which takes care of all Cart methods), usually: **add item**, **remove item**, **change quantity of item**, etc.

Two of common methods are also **increment/decrement item quantity** which you can use alongside ajax request on frontend.

Just start with M:N part and then add what you need along the way.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I would do:

- Create a `CartCollection` [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#custom-collections) with `CardItem` as model at `session_start()`
- [Put](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data) it into the session
- A `CartItem` is related to models that are or extend from `Product` *(to keep your system dynamic, flexible, encapsulated, maintanable and extendable)* and contain a `quantity`
- "Add to cart" adds one `Product` wrapped in `CartItem` to `CartCollection`

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this in your controller

```
 # Our function for adding a certain product to the cart
    public function addToCart(Product $product)
    {
        Cart::add($product->id, $product->name, 1, $product->price);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Then call the function with params in your blade file for e.g

```
   <div class="album-price">
     {{ number_format($product->price, 2) }} USD</p>
       <a href="{{ route('add', [ $product->getRouteKey() ]) }}">
       <!-- The button for adding the product to the cart -->
       <button class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
        </a>
      </div>
```

You can check here for more:
https://medium.com/@larstwolters/creating-a-simple-webstore-with-paypal-integration-in-laravel-6-7b8c58a4be16